# Play base64 wave or m4a using videogular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-audio, videogular

According to the doc

http://www.videogular.com/docs/#/api/com.2fdevs.videogular.direcitve:vgMedia

it only takes Url as the input. Is there a way to pass base64 into this, just like using `<source src="data:audio/wav;base64,` instead?

I am OK if this has to modify source code. It's a small project on the mobile.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of Videogular.

Maybe you can try by setting a source with a base64 and the media type. Videogular basically sets a string to the src attribute based on the type passed.

For example, in your controller:

```
this.config = {
    sources: [
        {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("data:audio/wav;base64,"), type: "audio/mp4"}
    ]
};
```

The main problem could be if you want to stream the base64 and pass data in chunks, but if you're sending in a base64 the whole audio/video it should be fine I think.